# Weird issue with GPS in my Android app

Tags: android, gps

There seems to be a problem with the communication between GPS and my android application.
About 1 in 10 times (after starting the application) the GPS isn't triggered by LocationManager.requestUpdates() (no GPS icon shows up etc.). 
I've built in a timer that checks the GPS status every 15 seconds and when the GPS isn't working it'll remove the updates from the LocationManager and requests the updates again (the GPS status is checked through GpsStatus.Listener). Sometimes this wakes up the GPS and the problem is solved, but most of the time this doesn't work. However, turning off GPS on the device and turning it back on [sometimes] fixes this as well. 
The application has lots of users with different devices who have this problem. I have a foreground service running at all times which requests these location updates in onStartCommand() and it removes the updates in onDestroy(). I've tried a lot of different solutions, but none of them seem to work (frustrating). I tried the fused location provider, but this doesn't always give the most accurate location/has no bearing/speed etc. Is there any other way to give the GPS a poke to wake it up or has anyone had this problem before? Also, I noticed that whenever this happens and I close the application, remove it from memory, and start it up again, the problem is fixed as well. It looks like something in the application is blocking it from communicating with the GPS (no idea if this is possible).

I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions as to what the problem could be.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, so I've been frustrated with this issue for a couple of weeks and apparently it's because of Flurry. Flurry reports GPS locations as well and this conflicts with the GPS of my app.. Calling `FlurryAgent.setReportLocation(false)` fixed this issue for me.